# Prove that G and H have the same number of finite subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we let $\psi:G\to H$ be a group isomorphism, can someone please help me on how to prove that G and H have the same number of finite subgroups?

Comment: But that's not true. Are you leaving information out?

Comment: Take the trivial map as a counter example @anon

Comment: Out of curiosity, why am I the recipient of your message, @Sean? :)

Comment: @anon: No, thats all thats given in the question. THanks

Comment: @anon Hmm, not sure..... was reading your comment as I posted I guess, hope you were not offended.

Comment: Did you mean isomorphism?

Comment: @Geoff: Yes Geoff, I meant isomorphism

Comment: As a sidenote, if $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, then "everything" is the same for $G$ ans $H$ - except their name perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean isomorphism (if not, $\psi(x) == e$ is a group homomorphism, but doesn't yield your result).

In that case, all you need is to show that if $F$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $\psi(F)$ is a subgroup of H. As you can invert the argument, and the image of different subgroups will be different (isomorphism), this is enough. To show that the image of a subgroup is a subgroup under an isomorphism, recall first the following:

*Lemma*: A non-empty subset $F$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup iff $xy^{-1} \in F$ if $x, y \in F$.

It's easy to prove if you don't have it in your notes. Using the lemma, if $x', y' \in \psi(F)$, then there are unique elements $x, y \in F$ mapping to them, as in $\psi(x) = x', \psi(y) = y'$ (isomorphism). As $F$ is a subgroup of $G$, $xy^{-1} \in F$ by the lemma. But then 
$$\psi(xy^{-1}) = \psi(x) \psi(y^{-1}) = \psi(x) {\psi(y)}^{-1} = x' (y')^{-1},$$
and so $x' (y')^{-1} \in \psi(F),$ so $\psi(F)$ is a subgroup of H, and you are done.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

***Hint*** $~~~$What we *can say* is the following:

For every isomormphism (and homomorphism) $\psi: G \to H$,

- If $F$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $\psi[F]\,$ is a subgroup of $\,H$, and
- if  $K$ is a subgroup of $H$, $\psi^{-1}[K]\,$ is a subgroup of $\, G$.

An isomorphism maps identity to identity, inverses to inverses, and subgroups to subgroups. It is "structure preserving." And the inverse of an isomorphism is itself an isomorphism.

---

Don't forget to use the fact that an isomorphism is *bijective*, hence every element in each group must have a counterpart in the other group which $\psi$ or $\psi^{-1}$ maps, respectively. And you need that this *necessarily implies* the groups $G, H$ are of equivalent cardinality, as are subgroups between which the isomorphism and its inverse map. Bijectivity is what will make the fact that $\psi: G \to H$ is an *isomorphism*, and not just a homomorphism, crucial to your proof.

Comment: thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. An example: $\psi (G)=1$.